# Is there a better way to pass "this" object to a callback function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to backbonejs. I am trying to pass the correct `this` object to a callback function where that function is a method of the view.

My current solution:

```
APP.LocationFormView = APP.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {    
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var that = this;

            var success = function(position) {
                _.bind(that.onSuccessUpdatePos, that, position)();
            };

            var error = function(error) {
                _.bind(that.onFailUpdatePos, that, error)();
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, 
                                                     error);
        } else {

        }
    },

    onSuccessUpdatePos: function(position) {
        // We can access "this" now
    },

    onFailUpdatePos : function(error) {
        // We can access "this" now
    }
});
```

Is this a correct way to achieve what I want?
Is there any less verbose solution for this?

Comment: If you plan to use CoffeeScript than you can avoid using bind by using fat arrows => in function definitions. Does the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it. One nice aspect of `bindAll` is that if you add additional functions to `LocationFormView` they will automatically have `this` bound.

```
APP.LocationFormView = APP.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {   
        _.bindAll(this); 
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onSuccessUpdatePos, 
                                                     this.onFailUpdatePos);
        } else {

        }
    },

    onSuccessUpdatePos: function(position) {
        // We can access "this" now
    },

    onFailUpdatePos : function(error) {
        // We can access "this" now
    }
});
```

Comment: _.bindAll(this);- that all what I need. Tnks!

Comment: Youll have to pass it the functions that need to be binded. In this case: `_.bindAll(this, 'onSuccessUpdatePos', 'onFailUpdatePos')`

Answer (score 2):

`_.bind` is for later binding. What you would normally do is this:

```
that.onSuccessUpdatePos(position); // that is already the context
```

But instead, you can just pass it directly:

```
var success = _.bind(that.onSuccessUpdatePos, that, position);
var error   = _.bind(that.onFailUpdatePos, that, error);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
```

That is, if that feels more clear to you than the "manual" solution.